# Change jquery selection scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I am writing a jQuery selectors within a specific-page javascript, I'd like to be able to use a simplified (scoped) selection mechanism.

To reference the element currently I need to use the full selector:

```
$('#home-view #events-cloud')'
```

Since the code line above is used within a home-view backing js file, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$.SetSelectorPrefix('#home-view');
$('#events-cloud');
```

Is there a possibility to do something to address the code-location specific selections?

Comment: Why would you ever need to set the scope to a parent element? Inside whatever function you have, you can just do `var that = $(this).closest('#home-view')` and you have a referrence to the parent element ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply modify the default jQuery init function so that the context is the one chosen by you:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
$ = function (selector, context) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context || document.getElementById('home-view'));
};
$.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;
jQuery.extend($, jQuery);
console.log($('#events-cloud'));
```

Explanation:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This line prevent jQuery's default assign to `$`.

```
$ = function (selector, context) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context || document.getElementById('wrapper'));
};
```

Assign to `$` the new modified function that will return a new jQuery instance with the context modified for your purposes(this is the clue of the script)!

```
$.fn = $.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Creates a new property `fn` to the `$` function, and assign it to the prototype inheriting properties from `jQuery.fn`.

```
jQuery.extend($, jQuery);
```

Extends the created object with jQuery functions, so you can use it exactly as jQuery.

See a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyftc/) of this snippet.

Comment: Good answer if the generic code need to use `$` without to know that it is scoped. But the `context ||` overwriting looses this transparency and become dangerous, since `$('#sel', '#ctx')` can find elements outside the scope (`'#home-view'`) :s

Comment: It is not dangerous, it is wanted. By using this you are allowed to use or not the context parameter. If you want to change the default context of jQuery you can add the parameter and you're done. Otherwise, as OP requested, when using the jQuery selectors they are forced, if no context is specified, to be searched in the default context. I think that OP wanted to use `$(selector)` as if it were `$("#home-view " + selector)`. Anyway, the "issue" can be easily avoided just by omitting the context parameter and the part `context ||`.

Comment: It's an issue when not documented. Now its a feature ;) - other undocumented issue (or feature ;)): `jQuery` is not scoped, only the shorthand `$`, which could save the face when using well written plugins (based on the initial `jQuery`), but a pitfall on which using global `$`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
var container = $('#home-view');
// Will only search elements within #home-view
container.find('#events-cloud');
// Changing container
container = $('#main-view');
// Will only search elements within #main-view
container.find('anotherSelector');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need genericity on your generic sections, otherwise you would not ask.

So a generic code could call `$('#selector')` without being aware of the context.

#### The simplest way: use a custom function $$

```
function $$(selector, context) {
    return $(selector, context ? $(context, $$.stack[0]) : $$.stack[0]);
}
$$.stack = [];
$$.push = function(context){ $$.stack.unshift(context); }
$$.pop = function(){ return $$.stack.shift(); }
```

In your generic sections use `$$('#selector')` instead of `$('#selector')`

Around your generic code execution use:

```
$$.push('#home-view');

// generic code call using $$
// e.g. $$('#events-cloud') <=> $('#events-cloud', '#home-view') <=> $('#home-view #events-cloud')

$$.pop();
```

With this custom function, you can nest contexts and even use the `$$(selector, localcontext)` form. Thus for the generic code, the current global context is totally transparent.